# Stackoverflow error in android java while passing to json after encoding to base64 string from byte array

Tags: android, arrays, json, zip, encode

```
byte [] byteArray = Files.toByteArray(zipFile);

String strLogEncode = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.URL_SAFE);

jObjLogdata.put("LogFilePath", "");

jObjLogdata.put("file_byte_array", strLogEncode);
```

Here String strLogEncode will be a large string contains "//" which will restrict json to send.
but I used different flag URL_SAFE,but now i'm getting some random errors. what's the possible way to fix this, i want to convert this byte array to string and send to json, so that i can handle this json and decode frombase64 at server side and store the zip file by doing some file operations.

sometimes it's working, depends on the file size i guess.

Comment: You fogot to post the exception, to mark where it occurs and most important what `jObjLogdata` is, respectively what happens with this object after the posted code snippet.

Comment: Exception: Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()

Comment: jObjLogdata is json object